# Mapping values from one to the other df based on multiple columns in both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mapping

I have two dataframes and would like to map the "K1" values from df2 onto a new column ["K1_mapped"] in df1, but only when the column values [["PC1", "PC2" and "PC3"]] are the same in the two dataframes.

DF1:

```
    PC1              PC2             PC3
1   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen
2   Kunststoffe      Profile         Plastikprofile
3   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen
4   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen
5   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen
6   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen
7   Holz             Vollholz        Brettschichtholzplatte
8   Holz             Holz            Holz
9   Holz             Vollholz        Brettschichtholzplatte
10  Baustoffe        Steine          Dachziegel
11  Daemmstoffe      Holzfasern      Holzfaserdaemmplatte
12  Daemmstoffe      Holzfasern      Holzfaserdaemmplatte
```

DF2:

```
    PC1             PC2                 PC3                     K1                  
1   Holz            Holz                Holz                    Boeden und Decken   
2   Holz            Vollholz            Balkenschichtholz       Boeden und Decken   
3   Holz            Vollholz            Bau-Schnittholz         Waende  
4   Holz            Vollholz            Brettschichtholz (BSH)  Waende      
5   Holz            Vollholz            Brettschichtholzplatte  Waende      
6   Kunststoffe     Dachbahnen          Elastomer-Dachbahnen    Dachkonstruktion    
7   Kunststoffe     Dachbahnen          PVC-Dachbahnen          Dachkonstruktion    
8   Kunststoffe     Dichtmassen         Acrylat                 Waende              
9   Kunststoffe     Profile             Plastikprofile          Fenster
10  Daemmstoffe     Holzfasern          Holzfaserdaemmplatte    Isolierung
```

Desired Output DF1_new:

```
    PC1              PC2             PC3                      K1
1   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen     Dachkonstruktion
2   Kunststoffe      Profile         Plastikprofile           Fenster
3   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen     Dachkonstruktion
4   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen     Dachkonstruktion
5   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen     Dachkonstruktion
6   Kunststoffe      Dachbahnen      Elastomer-Dachbahnen     Dachkonstruktion
7   Holz             Vollholz        Brettschichtholzplatte   Waende 
8   Holz             Holz            Holz                     Boeden und Decken
9   Holz             Vollholz        Brettschichtholzplatte   Waende 
10  Baustoffe        Steine          Dachziegel               NAN
11  Daemmstoffe      Holzfasern      Holzfaserdaemmplatte     Isolierung
12  Daemmstoffe      Holzfasern      Holzfaserdaemmplatte     Isolierung
```

I tried to map K1, but it only uses PC1 for mapping:

```
d1['K1_mapped'] = d1['PC1'].map(d2.drop_duplicates('PC1').set_index('PC1')['K1'])
```

But how can I incorporate "PC2" and "PC3" as determining factor for the mapping? - They should be equal in both data sets.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df1_new = df1.merge(df2, on=["PC1", "PC2", "PC3"], how="left")
```

Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for how `merge` works.

---

Result for

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'PC1': ['Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Holz', 'Holz', 'Holz', 'Baustoffe', 'Daemmstoffe', 'Daemmstoffe'],
     'PC2': ['Dachbahnen', 'Profile', 'Dachbahnen', 'Dachbahnen', 'Dachbahnen', 'Dachbahnen', 'Vollholz', 'Holz', 'Vollholz', 'Steine', 'Holzfasern', 'Holzfasern'],
     'PC3': ['Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'Plastikprofile', 'Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'Brettschichtholzplatte', 'Holz', 'Brettschichtholzplatte', 'Dachziegel', 'Holzfaserdaemmplatte', 'Holzfaserdaemmplatte']}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'PC1': ['Holz', 'Holz', 'Holz', 'Holz', 'Holz', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Kunststoffe', 'Daemmstoffe'],
     'PC2': ['Holz', 'Vollholz', 'Vollholz', 'Vollholz', 'Vollholz', 'Dachbahnen', 'Dachbahnen', 'Dichtmassen', 'Profile', 'Holzfasern'],
     'PC3': ['Holz', 'Balkenschichtholz', 'Bau-Schnittholz', 'Brettschichtholz (BSH)', 'Brettschichtholzplatte', 'Elastomer-Dachbahnen', 'PVC-Dachbahnen', 'Acrylat', 'Plastikprofile', 'Holzfaserdaemmplatte'], 'K1': ['Boeden und Decken', 'Boeden und Decken', 'Waende', 'Waende', 'Waende', 'Dachkonstruktion', 'Dachkonstruktion', 'Waende', 'Fenster', 'Isolierung']}
)
```

is

```
        PC1         PC2                     PC3                 K1
0   Kunststoffe  Dachbahnen    Elastomer-Dachbahnen   Dachkonstruktion
1   Kunststoffe     Profile          Plastikprofile            Fenster
2   Kunststoffe  Dachbahnen    Elastomer-Dachbahnen   Dachkonstruktion
3   Kunststoffe  Dachbahnen    Elastomer-Dachbahnen   Dachkonstruktion
4   Kunststoffe  Dachbahnen    Elastomer-Dachbahnen   Dachkonstruktion
5   Kunststoffe  Dachbahnen    Elastomer-Dachbahnen   Dachkonstruktion
6          Holz    Vollholz  Brettschichtholzplatte             Waende
7          Holz        Holz                    Holz  Boeden und Decken
8          Holz    Vollholz  Brettschichtholzplatte             Waende
9     Baustoffe      Steine              Dachziegel                NaN
10  Daemmstoffe  Holzfasern    Holzfaserdaemmplatte         Isolierung
11  Daemmstoffe  Holzfasern    Holzfaserdaemmplatte         Isolierung
```

Comment: Actually it doesnt work. It returns empty values. It should map the values where the values in the columns are the same.

Comment: @awi1100 Hm, works here with the sample dataframes you've provided? Are the data stripped (blanks at the end in one df but not in the other etc.)?

Comment: df1 is 7000 lines long, and df2 only 243. Maybe something about the index? There should be some that match, so I do not know why i only return nans for the added K1 column

Comment: @awi1100 The length shouldn't matter. (I've added my input and my result.) My suspicion is that the data might seem similar but actually isn't, due to blanks at the end etc.

Comment: @awi1100 Could you try to `strip` the columns of the dataframes: `for c in df1.columns: df1[c] = df1[c].str.strip()` and the same for `df2`.